# Bad value in function returning string and const char*

Tags: c++, string

I have this function in my program

```
const char* Graph::toChar() {
    std::string str;
    const char* toret;
    str = "";
    for (vector<Edge*>::iterator it = pile.begin(); it != pile.end(); it++) {
        str += (*it)->toString();
    }
    toret = str.c_str();
    return toret;
}
```

Then I'm debugging the function everything works properly until I'm in  *return toret;* line. I press step over and the debugger is going to *std::string str;* line and all string and charater variables become *""*, so the final return of the function is *""* (nothing).

What am I doing wrong?

*(*it)->toString();* is working properly and when the debugger executes *toret = str.c_str();* the value in *toret* is correct.

Thx

Comment: Why are you returning `char const*` rather than a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [string::c_str query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993848/stringc-str-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here is bad: You are returning the `c_str` of an `std::string` that's about to be deleted when it goes out of scope. regardless of debug mode or not, this means unpredictable behavior. actually rather predictable - your program will crash :)

You should either return `const std::string`, accept `std:string &` as an argument and build it, or use `strdup()` to copy the string's c_str to something that will stay in memory.  Keep in mind that using strdup() means you'll have to delete it somewhere later.

Here are two forms of the function that will work:

```
const std::string Graph::toChar() {
    std::string str;
    for (vector<Edge*>::iterator it = pile.begin(); it != pile.end(); it++) {
        str += (*it)->toString();
    }
    return str;
}
```

or

```
void Graph::toChar(std::string &out) {
    out = ""
    for (vector<Edge*>::iterator it = pile.begin(); it != pile.end(); it++) {
        out += (*it)->toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to return char const* because I want to use this function to call another program with system( graph->toChar() ); So, maybe other solution is to create a copy of the const char* ( str.c_str(); ) that won't be deleted out of the function. How can I do that? Or maybe another better solution

Comment: if you use for example my first example that returns a string, you can do: `system(graph->toChar().c_str());`