# C++ temporary variable lifetime?

Tags: c++

I know this is valid in C++, because temporary from `std::string("xxx")` lives to the end of the full expression it appears in.

```cpp
printf("%s\n", std::string("xxx").c_str());
```

And this is valid too:

```cpp
std::string f1() {
    return std::string("xxx");
}

void g1() {
    printf("%s\n", f1().c_str());
}
```

But is this valid? if not, why?

```cpp
const char* f2() {
    return std::string("xxx").c_str();
}

void g2() {
    printf("%s\n", f2());
    // or: std::string x = f2(); // is this valid?
}
```

Comment: An almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993848/stringc-str-query) that uses a named local variable rather than a temp `string` object in the return.

Comment: Think of it this way, there is no object and no instance of `char*`. (1) is simply `void print (std::string s) { printf ("%s\n", s); }`, (2) returns an instance of `std:string`, but (3) attempts to return `std::string` through `char*`. Now if (3) was `const char *getliteral (void) { const char *s = "xxx"; return s; }` you would be fine.

Answer (score 6):

The temporary `std::string` inside of `f2` is destroyed when the function returns. The `char*` will be dangling.

EDIT: In response to the comment, `std::string x = f2()` is also not valid. It's still bad to initialize a `std::string` from a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same rule applies. The full-expression in which the `std::string` was created in `f2` is

```
std::string("xxx").c_str()
```

together with the construction of the return value from it.

After this expression executed and the construction of the return value executed, the temporary `std::string("xxx")` will be destroyed. Since destruction of the temporary `std::string` makes the `const char*` obtained from `.c_str()` and copied into the return value invalid, the return value of the function cannot be used in any way.

For `f1` the same applies (details relating to temporary materialization and copy elision, especially in C++17, aside). The temporary `std::string` is destroyed after construction of the return value. But in this case this is not a problem, because the return value is not a pointer to something that was destroyed, but an independent `std::string` object itself. This `std::string` object will live until the end of the full-expression in which the call to `f1` appears, i.e. until the end of

```
printf("%s\n", f1().c_str())
```

The following would be fine as well:

```
std::string f3() {
    return std::string("xxx").c_str();
}
```

Here again, a new `std::string` is created in the return value, which will live until the end of the full-expression in which `f3` is called.

---

In practice, for `f1`, since `std::string("xxx");` is already a prvalue of type `std::string`, copy elision will be applied, so that there is really only one temporary object, the return value of `f1`. The intermediate temporary will be eliminated and the return value directly constructed from `"xxx"`. This is mandatory since C++17 and was allowed and common before C++17.